# How to insert footer dynamically in every page using HTML-Sheets-of-Paper?

Tags: html, css, footer

I would like to insert a custom footer in every page dynamically, showing date and page number.
I'm using css plugin [HTML-Sheets-of-Paper](https://github.com/delight-im/HTML-Sheets-of-Paper) to create a A4 format size.

I did a small code javascript to make the job. But, in print page the `div` container doesn't stay in wish position.

I know that this question can be easy to some guys, but I tried several alternatives that I could think, without success.

I got:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/gustavo_sdo/avr5jw41/2/show/

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.page-footer` to

```
.page-footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25cm;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @robert-eckhaus for the answer.
From this I got to the css that solved my question.

The final result and the code can be seen here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/gustavo_sdo/avr5jw41/4/show/